# How to authenticate ajax request sent via cordova app to django rest api

Tags: cordova, authentication, django-rest-framework

In my app,I'm sending file to django rest api for file upload via ajax request.I have disabled csrf token so that I can send request via app.Problem is anyone can send ajax request and get the results.

ajax request:

```
     var formid = document.getElementById('upload');
    var url = $('upload').attr( 'action' );
    var form = new FormData(formid);
   var remark = document.getElementById('remarkt').value;
form.append("remark", remark);
form.append("file", $("#filet")[0].files[0]);

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": url,
  "method": "POST",

  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form

}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

backend code:

```
class FileView(APIView):

  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)


  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
```

What should I do so that requests only from app will be accepted?

Comment: you can force https, and get the cordova app to post with an auth token or a username/password combo to authenticate?

Comment: Please help.I'm new to cordova.How can I get auth token in index.html to send with ajax request?